# JdbcTemlate - No qualifying bean of type available

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp

I want to configure on xml JdbcTemolate.

it looks like this

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db/postgres.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>


<bean id="namedJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

but I get such an error

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'jdbcMealServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'jdbcMealRepository'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'ru.demo.exercise.repository.jdbc.JdbcMealRepository' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636)
>     ... 61 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'ru.demo.exercise.repository.jdbc.JdbcMealRepository' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636)
>     ... 74 common frames omitted

This is my JdbcService:

```
@Service
public class JdbcMealServiceImpl implements MealService {
    @Autowired
    JdbcMealRepository jdbcMealRepository;

    @Override
    public Meal save(Meal meal) {
        return jdbcMealRepository.save(meal);
    }

    @Override
    public Meal get(int id) {
        return jdbcMealRepository.get(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Meal> getAll() {
        return jdbcMealRepository.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(int id) {
        jdbcMealRepository.delete(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Meal meal) {
        jdbcMealRepository.update(meal);
    }
}
```

JdbcRepository:

```
@Repository
public abstract class JdbcMealRepository implements MealRepository {

    private static final BeanPropertyRowMapper<Meal> ROW_MAPPER = BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Meal.class);

    @Autowired
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    private final SimpleJdbcInsert insertMeals;

    @Autowired
    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    protected JdbcMealRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {
        this.insertMeals = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcTemplate)
                .withTableName("meals")
                .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");

        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
        this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public Meal save(Meal meal) {
        MapSqlParameterSource map = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("id", meal.getId())
                .addValue("date_time", meal.getDatetime())
                .addValue("description", meal.getDatetime())
                .addValue("calories", meal.getCalories());

        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO meals(id, date_time, description, calories) " +
                "VALUES(id=:id, date_time=:date_time, description=:description, calories=:calories)", map);

        return meal;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class JspMealController {
    @Autowired
    JdbcMealServiceImpl mealService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    public String getAll(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("meals", mealService.getAll());
        return "meals";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/createForm")
    public String addForm(Model model) {
        Meal meal = new Meal();
        model.addAttribute("mealsCreate", meal);

        return "createmealForm";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/create")
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("mealsCreate") Meal meal) {
        mealService.save(meal);
        return "redirect:/list";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/delete")
    public String deleteMeal(@RequestParam("mealId") int id) {
        mealService.delete(id);
        return "redirect:/list";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/updateForm")
    public String updateForm(@RequestParam("mealId") int id, Model model) {
        Meal meal = mealService.get(id);
        model.addAttribute("mealsUpdate", meal);

        return "updatemealForm";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/update")
    public String update(@ModelAttribute("mealsUpdate") Meal meal) {
        mealService.update(meal);
        return "redirect:/list";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JdbcMealRepository should not be an abstract class. We must provide a concrete implementation class. Try removing abstract keyword from JdbcMealRepository class.